# Call webdriver from another package

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to set up a web app test suite using Selenium and Java. I am going to create 3 packages under src

- Objects - used for my page objects
- Tasks - used for testing methods
- Tests - used for the tests

Under Tasks I created a class called CommonTasks, which is used to store methods created for testing. Here are some examples.

```
protected void verifyNumberOfElements(By selector, int expectedsize){
        int size = driver.findElements(selector).size();
        log.info("INFO: Verifying the number of elements is "+expectedsize+"");
        Assert.assertEquals(size, expectedsize);
        log.info("PASS: The number of elements returned was "+expectedsize+" ");
    }

public static void verifyText(By selector, String expectedtext){
        //verify that the expected text is present
        String actualtext = driver.findElement(selector).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualtext, expectedtext);
        log.info("PASS: "+expectedtext+" was present and verified");
    }

protected void verifyElement(By selector){
        //Verify that a certain selector is present in the page
        smartSleep(selector);
        boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(selector).size() > 0;
        Assert.assertEquals(isPresent, true);
        log.info("PASS: Element was found");
        boolean notPresent = driver.findElements(selector).size() > 0;
        Assert.assertEquals(notPresent, false);
        log.info("FAIL: Element was NOT found");
    }
```

Under the Tests package, I create a class called ABC for testing feature ABC. I have some basic steps like below

```
verifyText(PageObjects.ItemText, "Multiple Choice - Single Answer Radio - Vertical");
verifyText(PageObjects.Progress_PercentComplete, "0%");
```

The issue I am having is I don't know where to create the webdriver. I want to be able to create many test classes and call any method created in the Tasks package. I know that I need to import the class from Tasks, but can't figure out the webdriver creation part. Both the Tasks and Test packages will reference driver, so how to I make this work? Does it need to be created in Tasks.CommonTasks, or Tests.ABC?

I will also need the test to connect to SauceLabs instead of my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code above, all your methods in the Tasks packages are utility methods and are common to your test suite so these methods are invoked from the Test methods only where your driver was initialized already so create your webdriver in your test class and pass it on to utility methods in the tasks package.

Hope it helps